# R: How to permute only column in a data frame/matrix

Tags: r, matrix, permutation, vegan

I want to create x randomised matrices where only the columns are permuted but the rows are kept constant. I already took a look at `permatful()` in the `vegan` package. Nevertheless, i was not able to generate the desired result even though i am quite sure that this should be possible somehow.

```
df = matrix(c(2,3,1,4,5,1,3,6,2,4,1,3), ncol=3)
```

This is (one possible) desired result

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    2
[2,]    3    1    4
[3,]    1    3    1
[4,]    4    6    3

           v
           v permutation
           v

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    2    2
[2,]    1    4    3
[3,]    3    1    1
[4,]    6    3    4
```

I tried something like `permatfull(df, times=1, fixedmar = "rows", shuffle = "samp")` which results in

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    2    2
[2,]    1    4    3
[3,]    3    1    1
[4,]    3    4    6
```

Now column 1 (originally column 2) has changed from 5,1,3,6 to 5,1,3,3.

Anyone an idea why I do not get the expected result?

Thanks in Advance,

Christian

Comment: You can just do `df[,sample(ncol(df))]` to randomly shuffle the columns

Comment: True, but i have to do it multiple times and i thought there must be a more sophisticated way than calling your function in a for loop

Comment: `dfshuffle <- lapply(1:n,function(i) df[,sample(ncol(df))])` will give you a list of  `n` random shuffles.

Comment: The [Andrew Guster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7727429/andrew-gustar) is a good approach. For more readability you can define the function before use `lapply` instead of use an anonymous function. `tranpose <- function(X) { col_index <- sample(ncol(X))  X[, col_index]}`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks for this alternative solution! Nevertheless i am still interested if this is also possible with the `permatfull` function

Comment: I've had a look at the documentation for `permatfull` and it says that 'If rows or columns are fixed, cells within rows or columns are randomised' - which sounds as if it is shuffling each row independently, rather than shuffling the columns (i.e. shuffling each row in the same way).  That would explain the result you got.  It might be that `permatswap` is the function you need, although I've not tried it.

Comment: No, you cannot use `permatfull` or `permatswap` for this task. They are functions to generate ecological null models (*sensu* Gotelli), but you want to have permutations of columns which is quite a different task.